# how to import data from csv file to mysql table?

Tags: csv, mysqlimport

I'm trying to load data from csv file to mysql table(already created). But loading failed. I tried directly without using query too "it shows error like 23 rows skipped".

I used the query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\Users\UserName\Documents\FILE.CSV'
INTO TABLE TABLE1 LINES SEPERATED BY '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this it maybe correct

load data local infile 'C:\Users\UserName\Documents\FILE.CSV' into table 
lines terminated by '\n'
(columns);